# Does the "bi" in bilinear and biorthogonal mean different things?

Tags: functional-analysis, multilinear-algebra

Does the "bi" in bilinear and biorthogonal mean different things? Bilinear seems to be linear from both left and right sides but biorthogonal means the product is zero sometimes instead of always?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bi* essentially just means *two*.

In *bilinear* it means linear in *two* arguments. In *biorthogonal* it means *two* families of vectors are orthogonal in respect to one another (but neither must be orthogonal in respect to itself). In *binomial* it means that there are *two* summands within the power, i.e. $(a+b)^n$. In *binary* it means that there are *two* possible digits, $0$ and $1$.